# Is Sweetalert2 html parameter length limited in size?

Tags: joomla, sweetalert2

I created a plugin for Joomla which uses Sweetalert2 and it generally works fine.
However, surprisingly, when the size of the html message I use is too long, the box does not popup and the content gets instead written to the document body itself...
Is there a size limit for the html parameter or could this somewhat be caused by Joomla?

Thx

Philippe

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. If you have Joomla questions, please ask them on JSE.

Comment: There's no size limit for the `html` parameter in SweetAlert2. The issue is most probably caused by Joomla.